# Fix div when scrolled at its bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a collapsible aside nav (so don't know the height of it) and a div under it, which should change `position` to `fixed` when scrolled at it's bottom.

I achieved this, but when I scroll back at top, the div stays fixed and I can't find solution to make it `static` again at the point where it was at the beginning, since I don't know where the exact point is.

Here is a fiddle (I explain my solution in js comments): https://jsfiddle.net/1krLnv7q/2/.

Could anybode help me, please? I am stuck.

Comment: Sounds like the `position: sticky` could do this. It's a shame it's only supported by firefox.

Comment: stuff like this can be done with `scrollmagic`'s pinning function. See http://scrollmagic.io/ and an according example at http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html

Comment: I've tried `position: sticky`, but switech to jQuery functionality due to its support.

Comment: Is it better to use jQuery or this css solution with pollyfil (https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can define your vars outside of the `scroll()` event, otherwise it will cause a buggy animation.

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/1krLnv7q/4/)

```
$(function(){
    //top offset of static/fixed div
    var staticOffset = $('.static').offset().top;
    //window height
    var wpHeight = $(window).height();

    //point when the user scrolls at the bottom of div
    //static/fixed div height + top offset - viewport height
    var treshold = staticOffset + $('.static').height() - wpHeight;

  $(window).scroll(function(){   
    //if user scrolls below the divs bottom (treshold) it becomes fixed
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > treshold){
        $('.static').addClass('fix');       
    }else{
      $('.static').removeClass('fix');      
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, such an elementary mistake. :(